# Fastest linear algebra library in terms of Cholesky factorization

Tags: java, linear-algebra

I'd really like assessing if any of you could point me towards the most optimized and computetionally quick linear algebra library in terms of **Cholesky factorization**.

So far I've been using the **Apache Commons Math** library, but perhaps there are more robust and better-enhanced options already available.

For instance, would `PColt`, `EJML` or `ojAlgo` better choices? The most urgent concerns is mainly one: I need to iteratively calculate (within a `2048` elements `for` loop generally) the lower triangular Cholesky factor for up to three different matrices; the largest size the matrices will reach is about **2000x2000**.

Answer (score 2):

Cholesky factorisation is quite a simple algorithm.  Here's the (unoptimised) C# code that I use.  C# and Java are quite similar, so should be an easy job for you to convert to Java and make whatever improvements you deem necessary.

```
public class CholeskyDecomposition {
    public static double[,] Do(double[,] input) {
        int size = input.GetLength(0);
        if (input.GetLength(1) != size)
            throw new Exception("Input matrix must be square");
        double[] p = new double[size];
        double[,] result = new double[size, size];
        Array.Copy(input, result, input.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < size; j++) {
                double sum = result[i, j];
                for (int k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--)
                    sum -= result[i, k] * result[j, k];
                if (i == j) {
                    if (sum < 0.0)
                        throw new Exception("Matrix is not positive definite");
                    p[i] = System.Math.Sqrt(sum);
                } else
                    result[j, i] = sum / p[i];
            }
        }
        for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
            result[r, r] = p[r];
            for (int c = r + 1; c < size; c++)
                result[r, c] = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Java Matrix Benchmark](http://code.google.com/p/java-matrix-benchmark/). The "Inver Symm" case test inverting a matrix using the cholesky decomposition. If you get the source code for the benchmark there is also a pure cholesky decomposition test that you can turn on.

Here's another [comparison of various matrix decompositions between ojAlgo and JAMA](http://ojalgo.org/performance.html)